# Scriptmanager not supporting for .net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, web-config

I am deploying a website which is developed in 3.5 framework.Server only support 2.0.

hence i recompliles the same project by changing the target framework.

But there is a scriptmanger in my website. which is not supporting 2.0 framework...

is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET 2.0 does support the use of AJAX, you just have to change the referenced assembly information.  You can get the needed files from the ASP.NET site [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/downloads/archive/).

Comment: You mean to say ..i have to install it on the server?

Comment: You install locally, then just deploy the dlls that are needed.